# Work done by pulling yourself up a platform

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work

I am struggling with the following problem:

> A platform has a rope attached to it which extends vertically upward, over a pulley, and then back down. You stand on the platform. The combined mass of you and the platform is $m$.
>   Consider the scenario where you grab the other end of the rope and hoist yourself up a height $h$ at constant speed.
>   a) What is the tension in the rope? (answer: $mg/2$)
>   b) How much work do you do? (answer: $mgh$)

I am struggling with b). The tension in the rope is $mg/2$, and the rope moves distance $h$, therefore the work done by me should be:
 $W=F\cdot d = (mg/2)h$
 This answer is incorrect and also doesn't make sense because I have gained $mgh$ potential energy. What's the problem with my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the rope goes both ways over the pulley. So, to move the platform (and yourself) upwards by a height $h$, the rope on both sides of the pulley decreases by a length $h$, so you need to pull a length $2h$ of rope. That is the flaw in your reasoning, which is your assumption that $d = h$. In reality, you *do* exert a force of $\frac{mg}{2}$, but over twice the distance.

Answer (score 0):

The rope shortens by the amount $h$ on both sides, so the work done will be $W=F\cdot d=\frac{mg}{2}\cdot 2h$.

You can also consider that you have done work to gain $mgh$ potential energy, that extra energy has to come from somewhere - it comes from the work done.

Answer (score 0):

Work is done on the unified mass $m$. The mass is pulled  upwards at **two** points. Total force on the mass is $2 * \frac{mg}{2} = mg$. Force * Distance $= mgh$.